NYI error when attempting to perform a union join
I am attempting to join a single-columned table to another table with several columns. The only column in the first table matches the title and type of the first column of the second table, but it has more values as the second table filters on a bigger master table and this single column takes all distinct values from the master for the specific column.
I want to return a table that shows all these distinct values, with the data from the second table stitched on, and NULL values where there is no data. As such, I try a union join:
nameList uj tbl;
But then I get hit with the below error unexpectedly:
nyi: Not yet implemented
I had a look at the documentation and I cannot wrap my head around what it means and what I am doing wrong. I attempted to add a dummy column to the first table so that I can key it but the join still does not work.
Could anyone please advise what I might be missing here?

Small dummy tables with example of desired output would be helpful.

An lj may be what you need instead
q)nameList:([] a:2 3 4 5)
q)tbl:([] a:3 4;b:6 7;c:8 9)
q)nameList
a
-
2
3
4
5
q)tbl
a b c
-----
3 6 8
4 7 9
q)nameList lj 1!tbl
a b c
-----
2
3 6 8
4 7 9
5


Is your second table keyed on that first column? In that case you would get an NYI
q)([] a:2 3 4 5) uj ([a:3 4]b:6 7;c:8 9)
'nyi
  [0]  ([] a:2 3 4 5) uj ([a:3 4]b:6 7;c:8 9)
                      ^
q))

because for a union join they have to either be both unkeyed or both keyed (on the same key). Since you can't key your one-column table you would have to have both unkeyed but I don't think that will achieve what you want.
As Rian pointed out you most likely want a left join. Or you could add a dummy second column to the first table but key it on that first column too ... then your union join would work
